# Multi Client Server - common way for 2 way connection in

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, sockets, client

I just want to know how the proper way of doing 2 way connection with one socket is (C#).

I need the client sending and also receiving data from the server without to open the port on the client-pc / router.

The server will be a multiplayer game server and the clients should not extra open a port to play the game.

So does a simple socket connection work in 2 ways (server has a socket listener, and client connects to the server socket)?

Hope that text pretty much explains my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the client can only connect to the port. Then, the Server may respond back to the client's connection

[image: Client-Server Request and its response]

**Example**

<sup>**Client**</sup>

```
IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9999);

  Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

  try
  {
     server.Connect(ip); //Connect to the server
  } catch (SocketException e){
     Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to server.");
     return;
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Type 'exit' to exit.");
  while(true)
  {
     string input = Console.ReadLine();
     if (input == "exit")
        break;
     server.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input)); //Encode from user's input, send the data
     byte[] data = new byte[1024];
     int receivedDataLength = server.Receive(data); //Wait for the data
     string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength); //Decode the data received
     Console.WriteLine(stringData); //Write the data on the screen
  }

  server.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
  server.Close();
```

This will allow the client to send data to the server. Then, wait for the response from the server. However, if the server does not respond back the client will hang on for much time.

**Here's an example from the server**

```
IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,9999); //Any IPAddress that connects to the server on any port
  Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); //Initialize a new Socket

  socket.Bind(ip); //Bind to the client's IP
  socket.Listen(10); //Listen for maximum 10 connections
  Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client...");
  Socket client = socket.Accept();
  IPEndPoint clientep =(IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
  Console.WriteLine("Connected with {0} at port {1}",clientep.Address, clientep.Port);

  string welcome = "Welcome"; //This is the data we we'll respond with
  byte[] data = new byte[1024];
  data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome); //Encode the data
  client.Send(data, data.Length,SocketFlags.None); //Send the data to the client
  Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from {0}",clientep.Address);
  client.Close(); //Close Client
  socket.Close(); //Close socket
```

This will allow the server to send a response back to the client upon the client's connection.

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: i get it. but what if the server needs to send data, without the client to whait for RESPONSE ?

Comment: i mean : one client is typing " hi everybody ", so the server gets thsi message and sends it to all the other clients, but if one client doesnt have typed anything befor, they are not waiting for the response.. do you know what i mean ?

Comment: @Ace Yes. The server has the opportunity to respond only if there were data sent by the client. It has also the opportunity to respond to the client after the client is connected.

Comment: `The server has the opportunity to respond only if there were data sent by the client` What does this mean? after a connection is established, client and server can send data whenever they want. No need to wait any data from other side.

Comment: @L.B 'only' here does not mean restrictions. It means that there's no need to wait for the client to send data in anyways. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple socket connection is a full-duplex connection i.e. yes, two-way communication is possible using a single socket.

[Here's a complete example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1430/Real-Time-TCP-IP-using-C).

Comment: so that way the client doesn't have to open the port ? so just the server needs to open it ?